# how to change the scale of the y axis to see better in a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, imshow

I currently have a scale problem with a heatmap:

[image]

As you can see at the beginning and at the end, there is a temperature variation, but as it is done on a very small distance and the scale is big, we can't see anything at all.

So is there a way or a function to fix this problem and automatically apply a better scale to see better ? To apply a small scale where there is a variation and a big scale when it is not ?

Here is the code to generate this image :

```
x = np.linspace(0,L,Nx+1) #array for y-axis
t = np.linspace(0.0, t_fin,Nt+1) #array to plot the time in the title

x = np.round(x,2) #change decimals 
t = np.round(t,5)


y = np.arange(T[Nt,:].shape[0]) #T[Nt,:] is an array that contains the temperature
my_yticks = x #change the number of points in the y-axis
frequency = 100


data = np.vstack(T[Nt,:]) #to use in imshow
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,9)) #plotting
titre = f"Température à {t[Nt]} s"
plt.ylabel('Profondeur en m')
plt.yticks(y[::frequency], my_yticks[::frequency])
im = plt.imshow(df, cmap='jet', aspect ='auto', interpolation='bilinear')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('Température en °C')
plt.title(titre)
```

If you have any questions, do not hesitate.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`logit`](https://matplotlib.org/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.LogitScale) scale on the y-axis. This won't however work with [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) as the values must be between 0 and 1 exclusively. You could use a [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

M,N = 100,20
a = np.array(M*[15])
a[:3] = [0,5,10]
a[-3:] = [20,25,30]
a = np.outer(a, np.ones(N))

fig, (axl,axr) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(3,6))

axl.imshow(a, cmap='jet', aspect ='auto', interpolation='bilinear', extent=(N,0,M,0))
axl.yaxis.set_ticklabels([f'{t/M*10:.3g}' for t in  axl.yaxis.get_ticklocs()])
axl.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axl.set_title('linear')

eps = 1e-3
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, N), np.linspace(1-eps, eps, M))
cm = axr.pcolormesh(X, Y, a, cmap='jet', shading='gouraud')
axr.set_yscale('logit')
axr.yaxis.set_ticklabels([f'{10*(1-t):.3g}' for t in  axr.yaxis.get_ticklocs()])
axr.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axr.set_title('logit')

cb = plt.colorbar(cm, pad=0.2)
```

[image]

**Warning**: setting the y labels as fixed values is only useful if you don't want to pan/zoom your image.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the y axis limit by ax.set_ylim([,])